# unable to send message from vertx3-eventbus-client in angular app, to vertx SockJs in backend

Tags: java, angular, vert.x

As [vertx document](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-sockjs-service-proxy/java/) mentioned, my java application creates a sockJs bridge to communicate with client via EventBus:

```
  router.mountSubRouter("/eb", sockJSHandler.bridge(options, be -> {
            if (be.type() == BridgeEventType.SOCKET_CREATED) {
                System.out.println("connection established..." + be.socket().writeHandlerID());
            }
            if (be.type() == BridgeEventType.RECEIVE) {
                System.out.println("received!...");
                if (be.socket().uri().contains("login")) {
                    handleLoginRoute(be);
                } else {
                    String socketId = be.socket().writeHandlerID();
                    AuthData authData = authDataMap.get(socketId);
                    if (authData == null)
                        be.complete(false);
                    else
                        be.complete(true);
                }
            }
        }));
```

and my angular component is like:

```
private host = 'http://localhost:8080';

ngOnInit(): void {

    const self = this;
    self.eb = new EventBus(this.host + '/eb');
    self.eb.onopen = () => {

      // set a handler to receive a message
      self.eb.registerHandler('login', (error, message) => {
        console.log('received a message: ' );
      });
      console.log('Send message: ');
      self.eb.send('login', {username: 'apple', password: 'red'});

    };
    self.eb.enableReconnect(true);
  }
```

The connection to the server establishes successfully but vertx server in java is not able to receive any message by the "send" method in client.

Comment: Have you tried `private host = 'ws://localhost:8080';` instead?

Comment: yes, did not work though

Comment: Can you try with `new EventBus(this.host + '/eb/');`